# aggregate three same lists based on two columns and sum the third column

Tags: c#

I have *three lists* of class type `AggClass`. I just need to *aggregate* these *three lists*.

```
public class AggClass
{
    private string _fan;
    private string _prefix;
    private decimal _amount;

    #region Properties

    public string Fan
    {
        get { return _fan; }
        set { _fan = value; }
    }

    public string Prefix
    {
        get { return _prefix; }
        set { _prefix = value; }
    }

    public decimal Amount
    {
        get { return _amount; }
        set { _amount = value; }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

If `Fan` and `Prefix` columns having same value then I just need make them as one column and `Sum` the `Amount`. How to do it?

```
LIST 1
FAN PREFIX   AMOUNT
F1    P1       10
F1    P2       20
F2    P2       50

LIST 2
FAN PREFIX   AMOUNT
F1    P1       30
F1    P3       20
F2    P2       30

LIST 3
FAN PREFIX   AMOUNT
F1    P1       10
F1    P3       10
F2    P2       30

OUTPUT
FAN   PREFIX   AMOUNT
F1      P1       50
F1      P2       20
F1      P3       30
F2      P2      110
```

I have to get output like this. How can I concat three lists same time? Is there any best way?

Comment: create a [dictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=net-5.0) to store fan prefix pairs as keys and the sum as values, then loop through all the lists and add the amount to the correct sum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use *Linq*: `Concat` (we concat all three lists into one) and then `GroupBy` (to combime all items by `Fan` and `Prefix`):

```
  using System.Linq;

  ...

  List<AggClass> list1 = ...
  List<AggClass> list2 = ...
  List<AggClass> list3 = ...

  ...

  var result = list1
    .Concat(list2)
    .Concat(list3)
    .GroupBy(item => new {Fan = item.Fan, Prefix = item.Prefix})
    .Select(group => new AggClass() {
       Fan    = group.Key.Fan,
       Prefix = group.Key.Prefix,
       Amount = group.Sum(rec => rec.Amount)       
     })
    .ToList(); // let's have a list as final result
```

If `group.Sum(rec => rec.Amount)` *doesn't compile* (I have .Net 5 where `Sum` accepts `decimal`), put `group.Aggregate(0m, (s, a) => s + a.Amount)` to sum `decimal`

**Edit:** Same idea for different columns (see comments below):

```
var result = eimsRecs
   .Concat(aaRecs)
   .Concat(mtrRecs)
   .GroupBy(f => new { f.FAN, f.Prefix })
   .Select(g => new Unbilled() { 
      Pid            = g.First().Pid, 
      AgrmntId       = g.First().AgrmntId,
      UnbilledAmount = g.Sum(rec => rec.UnbilledAmount),
      ...
    })
   .ToList();
```

Comment: you did groupby all the three columns, if we have 10 columns then we have to include all columns in groupby function??

Comment: @Venkat Krishna: I group by **two** columns: `item => new {Fan = item.Fan, Prefix = item.Prefix}`. If you have `10` columns you have to group by some *key* ("columns having same" as you've put it)

Comment: eimsRecs.Concat(aaRecs)
                                   .Concat(mtrRecs).GroupBy(f => new { f.FAN, f.Prefix }, 
                                                            f => f.UnbilledAmount)
                .Select(g => new Unbilled()
                {
                    Pid = g.First().Pid,
                    AgrmntId = g.First().AgrmntId,}).tolist();  But I am not getting PId and agrmnt id values

Comment: @Venkat Krishna: First, what are `PId` and `agrmnt id`? They are not mentioned in the question. It seems that you should `GroupBy` *entire* record `.GroupBy(f => new 
      { f.FAN, f.Prefix })` - note abscence of `f => f.UnbilledAmount`. I've edited the answer to be easy modifiable

Comment: how to sum the amount with new answer?

Comment: @Venkat Krishna: something like `UnbilledAmount = g.Sum(rec => rec.UnbilledAmount),`

Answer (score 0):

You can create a dictionary to store fan prefix pairs as keys and the sum as values, then loop through all the lists and add the amount to the correct sum.

```
....
List<List<AggClass>> allList = new List<List<AggClass>>();
allList.Add(list1);
allList.Add(list2);
allList.Add(list3);
Dictionary<string, AggClass> dic = new Dictionary<string, AggClass>();
allList.ForEach(item =>
{
    item.ForEach(agg =>
        {
            if (dic.ContainsKey(agg.Fan + agg.Prefix))
                dic[agg.Fan + agg.Prefix].Amount += agg.Amount;
            else
                dic[agg.Fan + agg.Prefix] = agg;
        });
});
List<AggClass> resultList=dic.Values.ToList();
```

Comment: how can i get other columns as well? I have PostDate column and I need to get Mindate of FAN Prefix combination. how can i do that?

Comment: Some notes: 1) You should use the `foreach` keyword instead of calling `list.ForEach`, it's much more readable. 2) Instead of saving the the concatenated string of the fan and prefix, you should use tuples, e. g. `(string, string)`.